# Construct a list of values which are not present in the current set

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has commodity, supplier and date (some other stuff also). I want to find all unique commodity,suppliers, date who dont have a date in the overall date set. Meaning from my values I find the set of all dates in the table and I want to construct a list of unique commodity,suppliers and date, which do not currently have a date property in the set. For example:

I have the data:

```
COMMODITY|SUPPLIER|DATE
-----------------------
1        |1       |15.06.16
1        |2       |22.06.16
2        |1       |29.06.16
```

I want the query to return:

```
COMMODITY|SUPPLIER|DATE
-----------------------
1        |1       |22.06.16
1        |1       |29.06.16
1        |2       |15.06.16
1        |2       |29.06.16
2        |1       |15.06.16
2        |1       |22.06.16
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Partition Outer Join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) this is easy to do:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 commodity, 1 supplier, to_date('15/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 commodity, 2 supplier, to_date('22/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 commodity, 1 supplier, to_date('29/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual),
             dts AS (SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM sample_data)
SELECT sd.commodity,
       sd.supplier,
       dts.dt
FROM   dts
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sample_data sd PARTITION BY (sd.commodity, sd.supplier) ON (sd.dt = dts.dt)
WHERE  sd.dt IS NULL;

 COMMODITY   SUPPLIER DT
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          1 22/06/2016
         1          1 29/06/2016
         1          2 15/06/2016
         1          2 29/06/2016
         2          1 15/06/2016
         2          1 22/06/2016
```

It also means that you only have to reference the table twice - once to get the list of unique dates, and again to join the table to the list of dates you're interested in, so it should be relatively performant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by constructing all possible combinations using `cross join`, then pick out the ones that exist:

```
select c.commodity, s.supplier, d.date
from (select distinct commodity from t) c cross join
     (select distinct supplier from t) s cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d left join
     t
     on t.commodity = c.commodity and
        t.supplier = s.supplier and
        t.date = s.date
where t.commodity is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as(
 select 1 as COMMODITY, 1 as SUPPLIER, '15.06.16' as "date" from DUAL
 union all
 select 1,2, '22.06.16' from DUAL
 union all
 select 2,1, '29.06.16' from DUAL
)

select *
  from (select distinct commodity, supplier from t),
       (select distinct "date" from t)
MINUS
select * from t
```